# Can I use Twilio's look up API with bulk SMS?

Tags: twilio, lookup, bulksms

It seems not reasonable using Twilio's lookup API for each message when I try to send out a bulk. It'll be too expensive and time consuming? So I'm wondering if there's a way or a technique I can integrate Twilio's Lookup API with my bulk.

Comment: What are you trying to solve for here?

Comment: I have an app that is capable of sending multiple sms at once and I'm trying to apply look up API once for each bulk SMS, not for each SMS. It's not only money consuming but also time consuming operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api) is not a bulk API. For each number you wish to lookup, you will need to make an individual request.

I would recommend that you don't look things up at the time of sending a bulk lot of messages, but that when you enter a user's phone number into your system you perform the lookup at that point and store the results alongside the number. That way you only need to perform the lookup once and it is done outside of your messaging API requests.